# Show/hide certain fields based on select list

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to use JavaScript and/or jQuery to hide certain html elements based on which item is selected in a drop down menu. The page looks like this:

```
[Drop down menu]

[text field 1]
[text field 2]
[text field 3]
[text field 4]
[text field 5]
```

The drop down menu has 3 options. For the first option, fields 1-4 should show. For the second, 2-4, and for the third fields 2-5 should be available.

I've got a [JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qRwDr/28/). Specifically, I don't get why

```
<option value="option3.com" onselect="$('#five').hide()">option3.com</option>
```

doesn't hide '#five'

Comment: I've updated your fiddle to include the css attribute selector and added basic jquery for capturing the selected value. [fiddle](http://goo.gl/42GCpw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no `onselect`, you probably wanted `onchange`.
Secondly, you're using jQuery, so use it.
Thirdly, change the markup to somehow include what you want, data attributes are great.

```
<select style="width: 120px;" name="farm_in" id="farm_in">
    <option></option>
    <option value="option1.com" data-show="[1,2,3,4]">option1.com</option>
    <option value="option2.com" data-show="[2,3,4]">option2.com</option>
    <option value="option3.com" data-show="[2,3,4,5]">option3.com</option>
</select>
<br>
<input style="width: 120px;" type="text" name="one" id="el1" value="one">
<br>
<input style="width: 120px;" type="text" name="two" id="el2" value="two">
<br>
<input style="width: 120px;" type="text" name="three" id="el3" value="three">
<br>
<input style="width: 120px;" type="text" name="four" id="el4" value="four">
<br>
<input style="width: 120px;" type="text" name="five" id="el5" value="five">
```

Then all you have to do is

```
$('#farm_in').change(function() {
    $('input').hide();
    $('#el' + $('option:selected', this).data('show').join(', #el')).show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qRwDr/30/)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this doesn't identify an element in your DOM:

```
$('#five')
```

You don't have an element with an `id` of `"five"`.  Instead, you're looking for this:

```
$('input[name="five"]')
```

(Or, conversely, you could give an `id` attribute to your elements.)

Aside from that, I'm not aware of any `onselect` event for an `option` element.  Why not respond to the `change` event of the `select` instead (and de-couple from the markup a bit while you're at it)?:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'option3.com') {
        $('input[name="five"]').hide();
    } else {
        $('input[name="five"]').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you fiddle you are missing the ID attributes for your text fields.

```
<input style="width: 120px;" type="text" name="five" value="five">
```

Should be:

Also I would recommend splitting you JS from your HTML.