# How to toggle multiple hidden fields to appear via CSS & Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to toggle multiple HTML fields to appear via a dropdown choice.

Let's say I have a dropdown with 3 choices: Branch, Region, & Division.

If I choose Branch, I'd like 3 fields to appear below it: Branch #, Site #, ID #.

I'm very early in my JavaScript knowledge, so I set it up like this, but it's not working:

```
$('select[name=YourLocation]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Branch') {
        $('#BranchNum').show();
    } else {
        $('#BranchNum').hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'Branch') {
        $('#SiteNum').show();
    } else {
        $('#SiteNum').hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'Branch') {
        $('#IDNum').show();
    } else {
        $('#IDNum').hide();
    }
});
```

and the CSS:

```
#BranchNum {
    display: none;
}

#SiteNum {
    display: none;
}

#IDNum {
    display: none;
}
```

Any help on how to restructure the JavaScript to allow me to toggle all 3 fields when one choice is made from the dropdown would be of great help! Thank you in advance.

This is the HTML for the Drop Down:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your Location</label>
        <select name="YourLocation" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Location</option>
            <option value="Branch">Branch</option>
            <option value="Region">Region</option>
            <option value="Division">Division</option>
        </select>
    </div><!-- /.form-group -->
</div><!-- /.col -->
```

And the HTML for the hidden fields:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="BranchNumber" placeholder="Branch #" id="BranchNum">
    </div>
</div><!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SiteNumber" placeholder="Region #" id="SiteNum">
    </div>
</div><!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="IDNumber" placeholder="Division #" id="IDNum">
    </div>
</div><!-- /.col -->
```

Comment: What's the HTML you have for this? And what is it doing or not doing?

Comment: please show example in jsfiddle.

Comment: I've added the HTML above. Basically, when I click "Branch" from the dropdown choice, I want it to toggle the three hidden fields "Branch #" "Site #" and "ID #" to appear

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nyj4vy5L/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide certain fields based on select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771293/show-hide-certain-fields-based-on-select-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this a lot by using a class instead of an ID like so:

```js
$('select[name=YourLocation]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Branch') {
    $('.BranchInfo').show();
  } else {
    $('.BranchInfo').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.BranchInfo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Your Location</label>
    <select name="YourLocation" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Location</option>
      <option value="Branch">Branch</option>
      <option value="Region">Region</option>
      <option value="Division">Division</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control BranchInfo" name="BranchNumber" placeholder="Branch #" id="BranchNum">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control BranchInfo" name="SiteNumber" placeholder="Region #" id="SiteNum">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control BranchInfo" name="IDNumber" placeholder="Division #" id="IDNum">
  </div>
</div>
```

What you'll want to do is add the class `BranchInfo` to each of the elements you want to hide/show, then the jQuery script will toggle all of them at once.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try this

Comment: Could just use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like `$('.BranchInfo').toggle($(this).val() === 'Branch');` then it's even shorter :).

Answer (score 0):

Taking your code and combining all your if/else statements into a single one, we have this.

```js
 $("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function() {
   console.log($(this).val())
   if ($(this).val() == 'Branch') {
     $('#BranchNum').show();
     $('#SiteNum').show();
     $('#IDNum').show();
   } else {
     $('#BranchNum').hide();
     $('#SiteNum').hide();
     $('#IDNum').hide();
   }
 });
```

```css
#BranchNum,
#SiteNum,
#IDNum {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Your Location</label>
    <select name="YourLocation" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Location</option>
      <option value="Branch">Branch</option>
      <option value="Region">Region</option>
      <option value="Division">Division</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>
<!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="BranchNumber" placeholder="Branch #" id="BranchNum">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="SiteNumber" placeholder="Region #" id="SiteNum">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col -->

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="IDNumber" placeholder="Division #" id="IDNum">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col -->
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you are using jquery. You could use jquery  `.show()`  to show the element you want to show and `.hide()`  to hide the other two when condition is met in your if  block.

Something like :

```
 if(conditions) {
    $('#elementToShow').show();
    $('#elementTohide1').hide();
    $('#elementTohide').hide();
 }
```

And do the the same with correct condition for other elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name=YourLocation]').change(function () {
     if ($(this).val() == 'Branch') {
           $('#BranchNum, #SiteNum, #IDNum').show();
     } else {
           $('#BranchNum, #SiteNum, #IDNum').hide();
     }
});
```