# How to display multiple hidden fields based on multiple dropdown choices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, model-view-controller

I posted the other day about how to toggle [multiple hidden fields to appear via CSS & Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812711/how-to-toggle-multiple-hidden-fields-to-appear-via-css-javascript)

I was able to implement it using one of the drop-down choices, in this case "Branch."

I want to, in the same application, be able to choose "Branch," "Region," and "Division" and have the corresponding hidden field that I choose, to appear. Here is the JSFiddle, not sure why I am unable to have them show: https://jsfiddle.net/4vup4dq8/

Any help would be great :) (This is the best community, you all have helped me so much!)

```js
$("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
  if ($(this).val() == 'Branch') {
    $('.RN').show();
    $('.BN').show();
    $('.DN').show();
  } else {
    $('.RN').hide();
    $('.BN').hide();
    $('.DN').hide();
  }
});

$("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
  if ($(this).val() == 'Region') {
    $('.RN').show();
    $('.DN').show();
  } else {
    $('.RN').hide();
    $('.DN').hide();
  }
});

$("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
  if ($(this).val() == 'Division') {
    $('.DN').show();
  } else {
    $('.DN').hide();
  }
});

$("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
  if ($(this).val() == 'Customer Care Center') {
    $('.CCC').show();
  } else {
    $('.CCC').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Your Location</label>
    <select name="YourLocation" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Location</option>
          <option value="Branch">Branch</option>
          <option value="Region">Region</option>
          <option value="Division">Division</option>
          <option value="Customer Care Center">Customer Care Center</option>
          <option value="Corporate">Corporate</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>
<!-- /.col -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control BN" name="BranchNumber" placeholder="Branch #" id="BranchNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control RN" name="RegionNumber" placeholder="Region #" id="RegionNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control DN" name="DivisionNumber" placeholder="Division #" id="DivisionNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <select name="YourCenter" class="form-control select2 CCC" style="width: 100%;" id="CCC" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Center</option>
            <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
            <option value="Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>
            <option value="Phoenix">Phoenix</option>
            <option value="Tampa">Tampa</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

.BN {
  display: none;
}

.RN {
  display: none;
}

.DN {
  display: none;
}

.CCC {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: what is your problem? seems working to me?

Comment: When I choose "Branch" I want "Branch #," "Division #," and "Region #" to display. When I choose "Region" I want "Division #" and "Region #" and when I choose "Division" I want "Division #" to appear. But when I click on "Branch" or "Region" only one choice is appearing. https://jsfiddle.net/4vup4dq8/

Comment: You are binding the change event 3 times on the same element. You need to do your logic inside one bind event.

Comment: @Helene ok check my solution.

Comment: Thank you Daniel :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First:** you don't need `$("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function() {} );` multiple times, you want one event handler for all situations.

Here I used `switch`, you can do it like `if`+`else if`+`else if`. But `switch` is a lot more simple.

The logic is by default `$('.RN, .BN, .DN, .CCC').hide();` will hide everything.

Note you can combine multiple selectors like this:

```
$('.RN').show();
$('.BN').show();
$('.DN').show();

/* equals to */
$('.RN, .BN, .DN').show();
```

Every time you change the dropdown, hide everything first. Then show the one you should show. In each switch `case` you can define each situation and in the `default` it is the default(else) situation.

```js
$("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function() {
  $('.RN, .BN, .DN, .CCC').hide();
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'Branch':
      $('.RN, .BN, .DN').show();
      break;
    case 'Region':
      $('.RN').show();
      $('.DN').show();
      break;
    case 'Division':
      $('.DN').show();
      break;
    case 'Customer Care Center':
      $('.CCC').show();
      break;
  }
});

//init
$('.RN, .BN, .DN, .CCC').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Your Location</label>
    <select name="YourLocation" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Location</option>
          <option value="Branch">Branch</option>
          <option value="Region">Region</option>
          <option value="Division">Division</option>
          <option value="Customer Care Center">Customer Care Center</option>
          <option value="Corporate">Corporate</option>
        </select>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>
<!-- /.col -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control BN" name="BranchNumber" placeholder="Branch #" id="BranchNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control RN" name="RegionNumber" placeholder="Region #" id="RegionNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control DN" name="DivisionNumber" placeholder="Division #" id="DivisionNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label></label>
      <select name="YourCenter" class="form-control select2 CCC" style="width: 100%;" id="CCC" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Your Center</option>
            <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
            <option value="Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option>
            <option value="Phoenix">Phoenix</option>
            <option value="Tampa">Tampa</option>
          </select>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply :) I will try this out. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Helene happy to help

Answer (score 3):

You have the same function running three times.

```
$("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function()...
```

When you pick "Branch", it runs the first time and shows all three.  Then it runs the second and third time, and hides the second two.  You need to combine your logic into one function.  Comment out the second two functions and you'll see it works when choosing "Branch".

Comment: Yes, I noticed it works when only doing it one time. How can I combine it so that it works with how I'm trying to display it? Thank you :)